PJSUA2 not detecting audio devices in Debian VM hosted on VirtualBox, VirtualBox on windows
I'm developing a SIP application using PJSUA2 in C++ on a Debian VM running in VirtualBox, hosted on a Windows 11 system. My application fails to detect any audio devices, and I'm not sure why.
Problem:
When running my application, the audio device count is always 0, which suggests that no audio devices are detected. Here's the relevant part of the code:
Initializing PJSUA2
Endpoint ep;
ep.libCreate();
EpConfig cfg;
ep.libInit(cfg);
std::cout << "Audio device count: " << ep.audDevManager().getDevCount() << std::endl;

What I've tried:
Checked VirtualBox settings for audio (set to Windows DirectSound, Intel HD Audio).
Ensured that the VM has guest additions installed.
Checked with aplay -l and arecord -l, both list the audio devices correctly.
Error Messages:
No error messages, but the device count returned is 0.
